# Rotating one-dimensional array of n elements left by m positions using constant memory?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, vector

Given a one-dimensional array of n elements, and a how would you efficiently rotate the array so that elements of the array to the left by m positions? Is it possible to do this in O(n) time complexity using only constant O(1) memory?

For example if n=8 and your array is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` and you rotate it to the left by m=2, you get `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1]`.

Here is the naive solution in Python I implemented which uses O(n) time and O(n) memory with a temporary array.

```
def rotateLeft(A, m):
    temp = [None]*len(A)
    for i in xrange(len(temp)):
        temp[i] = A[(i + m) % len(A)]
    for i in xrange(len(A)):
        A[i] = temp[i]
```

How could I do this more efficiently? I was told this could be done with a constant amount of memory and still in O(n) time.

Solutions in any language are okay and any suggestions are more than welcome.

EDIT: I am not looking for library solutions. Additionally, the array is not a linked list/deque. There is no notion of head/tail/next/previous elements.

Comment: Do you have to specifically use an array? If you used a LionkedList, you could do it in constant time: 1) point from the last element of the list to the first, 2) remove the pointer from the first to the second element.

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno Yes it's necessary to use an array. Otherwise the solution would be trivial. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at the **reversed** final array:

```
[1, 0,    7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]    (spacing mine)
```

Do you see something interesting?

Comment: Yes...in fact I do. :) This might just be what I'm looking for. [1, 0] is just [0, 1] reversed and [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] is just [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] reversed. Thus since reversing an array of size k is O(k) with swap, then all that needs to be done is reverse the array from 0 to m then reverse the array from from m+1 to n and then finally reverse the entire array. This is linear time O(n) and constant O(1) memory. Good job. :)

Comment: How does this compare to l[n:] + l[:n] ?

Comment: @Konchog Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Mbo, this is an intriguing answer but, unlike the OP, I don't quite get it.  My normal approach to rotating a list l by n points is done using slices->  l[n:] + l[:n] whereas you appear to suggest something that may be faster. I was wondering if you have compared the two approaches.

Comment: @Konchog l[n:] + l[:n] use additional memory, while task does not allow that. Note that some things might work faster when you use intrinsic Python functions (implemented in C) than hand-made plain Python solution with more perfect algorithmic approach.

Answer (score 5):

Try to think about what a solution like this would looks like. If you can't use more space, the only available move is to swap the elements. Try to do it with a pen, with a 2 elements array, then a 3. After you get the idea it should be quite easy.

In fact, using swap needs one more variable, you can fix this using the XOR swap algorithm ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm ), but I don't think this is really important.

Comment: A single temp variable for swaps is still constant memory.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't trivial due to the memory constraint. Start by moving the first element to it's new place, and since you can't store too many element - continue with finding a place for the element you just evicted.

Now think how the number of passes is related to GCD(n,m), and how your algorithm should reflect that - start by a common case where the gcd is 1 (for e.g. if m=3 in your example above) - once the chain of replacements will be over (you can check by comparing the current index with the one you started with), you'll have finished the task. However, for a GCD(m,n) > 1, you would have moved only part of the elements, and you'll need to start a new chain with the element right after the last one you started with.

Now convince yourself that the overall number of shift done is O(n), regardless of the number of phases.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following PseudoCode. Seems correct to me.

```
    function rotate(a[], a.length)
    {
     i = 0; 
     j = 0;
     k = 0; 
     temp = a[0];
     k = (i + a.length - 2 ) % a.length
     while (j < a.length){
     temp1 = a[k]
     a[k] =  temp;
     i = k;
     temp = temp1
     k = (i + a.length - 2 ) % a.length         
     j++
     }

     }
```

Comment: subtracting 2 (Value of m)

Answer (score 0):

This is one constant memory solution which was hinted to me by @MBo. It uses 3 extra variables in addition to the array space and m: `i`, `midpoint`, and `endpoint`. It loops 3 times, first reversing two subarrays and then reversing the entire array in the final loop. It is O(n/2 + m/2 + (n-m) /2) which is just O(n) since 0 <= m < n due to the fact that I do `m = m % n` at the beginning to reduce any given positive m to an index within the array's range.

Swapping also sends the values through a 2-item buffer (a tuple of 2 elements) but it's still constant memory for swaps so it doesn't matter.

```
def rotateLeft(A, m):
    m %= len(A)
    # Reverse A[0..m-1]
    midpoint = m/2
    endpoint = m-1
    for i in xrange(midpoint):
        A[i], A[endpoint-i] = A[endpoint-i], A[i]
    # Reverse A[m..n-1]
    midpoint = m+(len(A)-m)/2
    endpoint = len(A)-1
    for i in xrange(m, midpoint):
        A[i], A[endpoint-(i-m)] = A[endpoint-(i-m)], A[i]
    # Reverses all elements of array in place
    midpoint = len(A)/2
    endpoint = len(A)-1
    for i in xrange(midpoint):
        A[i], A[endpoint-i] = A[endpoint-i], A[i]
```

It also allows negative rotations (rotations to the right) which is really neat in my opinion. This means that `rotateRight` can be implemented in the following way.

```
def rotateRight(A, m):
    rotateLeft(A, -m)
```

And then the following code will then pass the assertion check just fine.

```
A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
B = A[:] # Make copy of A and assign it to B
rotateLeft(A, 4)
rotateRight(A, 4)
assert(A == B)
```